# Pandas df.to_csv() saves the old version of my file instead of the one i have modified

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, export-to-csv

I have a dataframe i'm replacing the NaN and zero values on. It all looks good when it's in jupyter notebook but when i use df.to_csv() it creates basically a copy of the original dataframe with all the zeros and NaN values.

I have tried every combination and way to write the path to where it should go.

```
df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Eddie\Downloads\pandas\Deformation.txt", error_bad_lines=False)
df.dropna(axis=1, how="all", inplace=True)

suffixes = ["_A", "_B"]

for suffix in suffixes:
    # Välj ut alla DIG*_*-kolumner och spara i en lista
    dig_cols = [col for col in df.columns if (col.replace(" 
    ","").startswith("DI") and col.endswith(suffix))]

    # Säkerställ att alla DIG*_*-kolumner är decimaltal
    for col in dig_cols:
        df[col] = df[col].astype(float)
        df[col].replace(0, np.nan, inplace=True)
        df[col].fillna(method="ffill", inplace=True)

path = r"C:\Users\Eddie\Downloads\pandas"
df.to_csv(os.path.join(path, "Deformation_new.txt"))
```

Comment: Try using a relative path first: `df.to_csv("Deformation_new.txt")` instead of the absolute path. It will write the csv in the current directory from which you run the script. But that shouldn't be the problem anyway. Right before you write the df to the file, print it and check if it's actually being modified by the previous code.

Comment: We can't launch the code because there is no [mcve], but as a note : You shouldn't use `inplace` parameter in pandas. It is going to be a deprecated parameter in 1.0, and deleted in like a year. So, just saying : Don't implement that on your production code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have tried using the absolute path. I also tried printing it right before i write the df to the file, and then it looks good, that’s the frustrating part about this that makes no sense. Also, i didn’t know that about the inplace parameter, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You Should try with the absolute path as follows, However when you use `to_csv`  it means `comma` separated Values ,So, you may either want to export values by `comma` separated or `tab` separated which you can define While working with `DataFrame.to_csv` method.

**For comma Separated Values:**

```
df.to_csv(r"C:\Users\Eddie\Downloads\pandas\Deformation_new.txt", sep=",", index=False)
```

**For tab Separated Values:**

```
df.to_csv(r"C:\Users\Eddie\Downloads\pandas\Deformation_new.txt", sep="\t", index=False)
```